# Pass value into dialog window in jQuery UI and to AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of items on a page that when clicked trigger UI's modal dialog.

```
var $dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true 
});

$(".myLink").click(function(){
    $dialog.dialog("open");
    $("#dialog").dialog({
    var delURL = $(this).attr("href").split("#");
    var delID  = delURL[1]; 
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function() { 
                // need to add AJAX call here
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "some.php",
                    data: "delete=delID",
                    success: function(msg){
                        alert( "Deleted: " + msg );
                    }
     });
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            }, 
            "Cancel": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            } 
        }
    });
});
```

I need to pass anchor value to another page when "Delete" button is clicked. I thini I need to use AJAX.

```
<a href="#val_1" class="myLink">Value 1</a>
<a href="#val_2" class="myLink">Value 2</a>
<a href="#val_3" class="myLink">Value 3</a>
```

Not sure how to do it.

Comment: Where is the element with class = myLink ??

Comment: Good catch, sorry I forgot to put class in links.

Comment: I updated my question. I know how to get the value from link and need to pass it to a script via ajax to do some db manipulation.

Comment: This is correct.
so what do you want now ?

Comment: Does my AJAX look right? It does not seem to be working...

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to change

```
data: "delete=delID",to <br />
data: "delete="+delID,
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing the line
`$(".myLink").click(function(){`
to
`$(".myLink").live("click", function() {`
however there is a bug in the lines when I test it. To get the dialog you should move the lines 

    `var delURL = $(this).attr("href").split("#");
    var delID  = delURL[1];`

above 
    `$dialog.dialog("open");`